# Quit a running command based on output in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a process which I start running using

`$ somecommand build`

It basically installs an app on an Android emulator and then starts up the emulator. This process keeps running forever until i manually kill it.

This command outputs a bunch of debug info into the terminal, also while running the app. I'd like to kill the command when somewhere in this continuous output, the string `[TESTS_ENDED]` has been outputted on the terminal.

Any oneliner on how to do this?

Comment: Check out this question: http://superuser.com/q/402979/4706 and specifically the `grep -m` answer: http://superuser.com/a/403041/4706

Comment: i like the `grep -m` solution, however my script now doesnt output anything,
and throws an unhandled exception since its some npm module im running.

Any way to still output onto terminal until the match is found?

As an additional requirement it would be neat if I could select the text between `[TESTS_STARTED]` and `[TESTS_ENDED]` and only output that (still killing the process on the `[TESTS_ENDED]`

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, with help from `pkill`:

```
somecommand build | awk '/\[TESTS_ENDED\]/ {system("pkill somecommand")}'
```

- Assuming only one instance of `somecommand` is runnning
- `\[TESTS_ENDED\]` matches `[TESTS_ENDED]` in the line
- If matched, `{system("pkill somecommand")}` will be run i.e. `awk` will use `system()` function to run `pkill somecommand` i.e. `somecommand` will be killed by `pkill`

Comment: the only reason i dont really like this solution is that it's assuming a single instance. It would be neat if you could refer to the instance that is being piped