# AWK taking action on a running output in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to use the output of a command, which is:

```
nmap -n -Pn -sS --vv <*IPs*>
```

The output of this command is devided into 2 parts; first a discovery and after that a port scan, both of them separated by the very first line that says

> Nmap scan report for <*FirstIP*>

What I need is the output of this first part, which by the way is the fastest one, and I need to pipe it to a further command/s (`awk`, `grep` or whatever) to filter only the IP addresses. Obviously, the intention of doing this is the need of stopping the running command exactly when the line "`Nmap scan report for <*FirstIP*>`" appears on the shell (first, because I don't need the other part and second, because the other part takes too much time!)

I found a very close solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762233/quit-a-running-command-based-on-output-in-bash) but it didn't worked because it executes both commands (`nmap` and `awk`) but there's no output in stdout in shell.

I would be looking for something like this:

```
nmpa -n -Pn -sS --vv <*IPs*> | awk '/Not shown/ {system("pkill nmap")}' | awk '/^Discovered/{print $6}'
```

But obviously this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want the awk to terminate when it sees the line `Nmap scan report`, then just add `/^Nmap scan report/{exit}` into the awk script.

Comment: Thanks @William, but I still don't see the IP addresses I need. That only stops the command, now how do I filter after that th IPs I need?

Answer (score 2):

Given this command line:

```
left-side | right-side
```

The problems you have are:

1. The shell will buffer the output of any command going to a pipe so you may not see "Not shown" in the right-side command until after the left-side command has finished running, and
2. You want the left-side command to stop running as soon as the right-side command sees "Not shown"

For the first problem, use [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) or similar.

For the second - exiting the right-side command will send a terminate signal back to the left-side command so you don't need to do anything else, what you want to happen will simply happen when you exit the right-side command.

So your command line would be something like:

```
nmap -n -Pn -sS --vv <*IPs*> |
stdbuf awk '/Not shown/{exit} /^Discovered/{print $6}'
```

idk if you meant to use "Not shown" or "Nmap scan report for" in your sample code. Use whichever is the string you want awk to exit at.

Comment: Which mode is `stdbuf` using for stdin/stdout if you omit arguments? Also `nmap` might/will buffer it's output. Doesn't it need a second `stdbuf` to prevent that?

Comment: Unbuffered. idk what nmap does so idk about it's output buffering, the OP can try it and see (or google...).

Comment: Maybe line buffering (i.e. stdbuf -iL -oL) would make sense in this scenario?

Comment: Could be. Let's consider it an opportunity for the OP to investigate further :-).

Answer (score 2):

Most flavors of awk do buffering.  There's no option to do what you're doing in gawk, but if you use [mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html), you can give it the `-Winteractive` option, which does not buffer.

Incidentally, you are running two awks, but you only need one:

```
nmap -n -Pn -sS --vv <*IPs*> | mawk -Winteractive '/Not shown/ {system("pkill nmap")} /^Discovered/{print $6}'
```

Every predicate in awk runs the associated block.  (Although I love awk, this use case might match [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) better.)

Comment: I don't think `awk` is doing the buffering on it's own. This happens in the glibc and can be influenced by the `stdbuf` command.

Comment: I haven't looked through nawk, but gawk (see io.c) and mawk (fin.c) appear to do their buffering internally.

Comment: What makes you think that `gawk` handles io buffering in io.c?